# How to escape # and = symbols with csv.writer?

Tags: python, csv, escaping, export-to-csv

[image]I am using Tweepy's Streamlistener (with Python 3.6) to stream twitter data. So far so good. Unfortunately, when converting them into CSV files, the programs seem to confuse or misinterpret certain symbols (= and # in particular) so that the texts get split and the columns messed up. (More concretely: the "text" column containing the tweets message is often split due to a # or a = in the sentence. The rest of the sentence is then filled into the next column etc.). 
I've read that this can be most likely prevented using the csv.writer and the writer row(s) method with some form of escape option. Could someone help me figure out how I could incorporate this in the two following codes?

Code 1: User's Timeline (relevant part)

```
outtweets = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.place, tweet.lang, tweet.retweeted, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count, tweet.entities, tweet.id_str, tweet.text] for tweet in alltweets]

    #write the csv  
    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["created_at","place", "language", "retweet", "retweet_count", "favorite_count", "entities", "tweet_id", "text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

pass
```

Code 2: Streamlistener (this code converts an existing jsonl file with the tweets into csv)

```
import json
import csv
import io

'''
creates a .csv file using a Twitter .json file
the fields have to be set manually
'''

def extract_json(fileobj):
    """
    Iterates over an open JSONL file and yields
    decoded lines.  Closes the file once it has been
    read completely.
    """
    with fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            yield json.loads(line)    


data_json = io.open('stream_____.jsonl', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') # Opens in the JSONL file
data_python = extract_json(data_json)

csv_out = io.open('tweets_out_utf8.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8-sig') #opens csv file


fields = u'created_at,text,screen_name,followers,friends,rt,fav' #field names
csv_out.write(fields)
csv_out.write(u'\n')

for line in data_python:

    #writes a row and gets the fields from the json object
    #screen_name and followers/friends are found on the second level hence two get methods
    row = [line.get('created_at'),
           '"' + line.get('text').replace('"','""') + '"', #creates double quotes
           line.get('user').get('screen_name'),
           str(line.get('user').get('followers_count')),
           str(line.get('user').get('friends_count')),
           str(line.get('retweet_count')),
           str(line.get('favorite_count'))]

    row_joined = u','.join(row)
    csv_out.write(row_joined)
    csv_out.write(u'\n')

csv_out.close()
```

Comment: Why not just use the `csv` module to handle CSV writing and quoting?

Comment: I tried to read through the Python's "CSV File Reading and Writing". My problem is that I don't know where I could insert the commands (and which one would be the correct one). For instance, in the first code, could I add the quotechar (?) command in :  writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar='"')?

Comment: The defaults is `csv.writer` should work, assuming you are viewing the .csv in Excel, the defaults are compatible with what Excel expects.  Follow what you did in Code 1, but also add `newline=''` to the `open` call.  Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6. And yes, I'm opening the file in excel although the same problem appears in TextEdit too. Will try!

Comment: I added the "newline" command within the open call, but unfortunately I still have the same result. I added a screenshot of the output for clarification.

Comment: I don't see what the issue is. Excel may or may not be displaying columns in different ways, but your data is all there without issue. There are no split columns.

Comment: maybe I'm overstitching the issue but for further analysis I would need all the text data in the same column. If you look at line 3, the arabic text is actually part of line 2's "text" column. The text was split, most probably due to the #? In other files I have similar issues with the = symbol